Clarifying Screen Density Categories in Google Play Statistics
Google Play statistics break down screen density as follows:
MDPI: 160 DPI
HDPI: 240 DPI
XHDPI: 320 DPI
XXHDPI: 480 DPI
XXXHDPI: 640 DPI

I would like to know how Google Play categorizes screen densities. Specifically, for DPIs such as 340, 360, and up to 450, will these be categorized as XXHDPI or XHDPI?
Thank you.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232895/295004

"This is because the device manufacturer is able to choose the density bucket." Thanks. In such a case, it is better for me to determine XXHDPI using the density folder rather than getDisplayMetrics, even though sometimes I am getting Resources$NotFoundException

Are you using one of the Display Metric constants: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#summary  And note the warning from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics#densityDpi applications should not strongly rely on density matching one of the enum constant

Thanks for the additional info. I am using this methodology - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/f22654c330c863937290da5000ef7d68

Not sure if it matters but II don't see mdpi or tvdpi in your gist.
